# Facing an error while building a custom skil for amazon alexa

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to a build a basic custom alexa skill. I have created an intent schema and am using AWS lambda function as the endpoint. ]

My Intent schema:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "toit brewpub",
            "modelConfiguration": {
                "fallbackIntentSensitivity": {
                    "level": "LOW"
                }
            },
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "GetClosingTime",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "what time do you close",
                        "when is the last order",
                        "till what time are you open",
                        "What time does the pub close"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "GetPriceOfBeer",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "beer",
                            "type": "BEERS"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "how much is {beer}",
                        "what is the price of {beer}"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "BEERS",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "Toit Red"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "Tiot Weiss"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "Basmati Blonde"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "Tintin Toit"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "IPA"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "Dark Knight"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am using **Node.js** `v 10.x` for my lamda function which has been built using **Alexa-Skills-NodeJS-Fact-kit**, The region for my aws lambda is **US_EAST- N.VIRGINIA**.

Below is the request I receive when I talk to my Test Simulator:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": false,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.fd1c5315-ecf8-413f-ba25-e54bd6ae316a",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.72615503-5f38-4baf-b0dd-cd6edd3b6dfd"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": ""
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.72615503-5f38-4baf-b0dd-cd6edd3b6dfd"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": ""
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": ""
        },
        "Viewport": {
            "experiences": [
                {
                    "arcMinuteWidth": 246,
                    "arcMinuteHeight": 144,
                    "canRotate": false,
                    "canResize": false
                }
            ],
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "pixelWidth": 1024,
            "pixelHeight": 600,
            "dpi": 160,
            "currentPixelWidth": 1024,
            "currentPixelHeight": 600,
            "touch": [
                "SINGLE"
            ],
            "video": {
                "codecs": [
                    "H_264_42",
                    "H_264_41"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Viewports": [
            {
                "type": "APL",
                "id": "main",
                "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                "dpi": 160,
                "presentationType": "STANDARD",
                "canRotate": false,
                "configuration": {
                    "current": {
                        "video": {
                            "codecs": [
                                "H_264_42",
                                "H_264_41"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": {
                            "type": "DISCRETE",
                            "pixelWidth": 1024,
                            "pixelHeight": 600
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.24b64895-3f90-4a5b-9805-9d3b038cd323",
        "timestamp": "2020-03-29T08:59:54Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed the user Id, device ID and access token while asking the question for security reasons.

My Lambda node js function looks like this which i have generated using the code generator :

https://github.com/shreyneil/Episodes/blob/master/amazon-echo/lambda-function.js

Url for code-generator: http://alexa.codegenerator.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Url for tutorial that i was using to implement it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB3wwxgqPOU

Whenever i try to launch the event using , `open toit brewpub`  in my test simulator it thorws an error stating :

> There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Any idea on how to make this work?

Any leads would appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: You have to check your cloudwatch logs to see what's wrong, because error `An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill` means, that exception was thrown in the code and which was not handled. If there is no exception there, then make sure that json you send back is in correct format.

Comment: I checked the cloudwatch logs, it shows that is was unable to resolve ask-sdk. While i have included the ask-sdk in my package.json and consequently deployed it. So i am unable to figure out how to fix this

Comment: How are you. deploying your skill and how are you importing 'ask-sdk' in your code?

Comment: i was using 'require' to import ask-sdk and i was using aws lambda endpoint for node js which i would  save and deploy after entering my business logic.  I have provided the link for my lambda function , u can refer that.

Comment: Code looks correct. In this case, there is something with packages. Are you using alexa-hosted code solution or are you deploying code yourself straight to lambda? Can you try downloading code from lambda and checking if it has node_modules in it?